# Installing Laravel and PHP version - wrong reading

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-12.04, ispconfig

I am trying to install laravel using composer on a specific website.
The default php version for the server is 5.3.10, but I have optional php installed and enabled using ISPCONFIG control panel.
The PHP version enabled for this website is PHP7.0.12

While using `composer install` I am getting
 `- laravel/framework 5.2.41 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.3.10) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Even when trying to put a phpinfo file in the root directory of the folder and accessing it through browser I am getting php 7.0.12 correctly working for this website.
How can address this issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 12 is fairly old. Is it possible to upgrade?

Comment: I have included that in the tag. it is ubuntu-12.04

Comment: ok resolved. I got the solution. `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Sure, that will install laravel but it will probably break on php 5.3 at some point.

Comment: however, composer install using the cli sapi , while when you write `phpinfo()` and browse it you are using the http server sapi

Comment: @hassan - is there any other way to overcome this issue.

Comment: make sure that you've switched the http server version too